Why do people say that the virtual DOM is more efficient than the actual DOM?
Any answer to what the question of what the difference is between virtual DOM and the DOM in React will inevitably tell you that it's more efficient because React only updates the elements that it needs to as opposed to refreshing the entire thing. Now, this sounds weird to me because any GUI system (at least any retained mode GUI, maybe not immediate mode) has a system in place whereby if an element/window/widget is changed it only updates that which it is necessary to update with sometimes very elaborate heuristics/algorithms. By that I mean any browser will already have this in place as part of its GUI system. Is this not the case? If so why do people keep mentioning this as a unique feature of the React DOM or virtual DOM?

The virtual DOM is more efficient when it comes to applying the changes, not just doing the diffing, Manipulating DOM using the browser APIs is less efficient than just manipulating them in your memory and then batching your updates in one call instead.

@MustafaReda Hmm, that's interesting. I have some experience with GUIs and I know that this is something that's done as much as possible generally by default. If you have use GUI library I guess what you're saying is the equivalent of a preprocessing step and batching all operations and then updating the gui all at once, which, I'm guessing is just a bunch of repeated API calls anyway. I guess I don't really understand what that means for the moment.
